# How to make rounded bottom navigation in Android Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, bottomnavigationview

I want to make a Bottom naviation in Android Jetpack compose but in every source I found, The navigation built with compose is normal, flat one
Just like This,
[image]

The point is I could not find a way to make something like this

[image]

How can I do just a thing ?
Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just use `clip` `Modifier` and add `RoundedCornerShape` with the top corners , here is sample code

```
BottomNavigation(
            backgroundColor = colorResource(id = R.color.black),
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().clip(RoundedCornerShape(15.dp, 15.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp))
        )
```

Comment: tried this out but still same :(

Comment: I verified Monohars solution. It works fine for me too. Do you use latest libraries of jetpack compose and its material components? @OğuzhanAslan

Comment: Silly me , I updated my libraries  and this solution worked

Comment: Doesn't work with compose 1.2.0

Comment: this solution works but color of cut areas of BottomNavigation is not the same as content's bg color.

Answer (score 3):

Use `clip` and `RoundedCornerShap`:

```
var selectedItem by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
val items = listOf("Songs", "Artists", "Playlists")

Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomStart) {
    BottomNavigation(modifier = Modifier.clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 20.dp, topEnd = 20.dp))) {
        items.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
            BottomNavigationItem(
                icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Favorite, contentDescription = null) },
                label = { Text(item) },
                selected = selectedItem == index,
                onClick = { selectedItem = index }
            )
        }
    }
}
```